# Jenkins: Export environment variables from a class extending SimpleBuildWrapper

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hashicorp-vault

I have a jenkins plugin that I wrote recently to source environment variables from secrets in a [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

For the most part everything works the way I expect, except when I expect a shell command to be aware of the environment variables that are set. I am setting the environment variables in the overridden [setUp](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildWrapper.html#setUp(jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper.Context,%20hudson.model.Run,%20hudson.FilePath,%20hudson.Launcher,%20hudson.model.TaskListener,%20hudson.EnvVars)) method of the [SimpleBuildWrapper](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildWrapper.html) class.

Here is a relevant snippet of how I am setting the environment variables:

```
for (VaultSecretValue value : vaultSecret.getSecretValues()) {
  context.env(value.getEnvVar(), values.get(value.getVaultKey()));
}
```

If I add a build step to echo the environment variable it returns the expected output, however, if I use an external command in the build step that expects the variable to be set there appears to be issues, something like the AWS cli:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-instances
```

If I take the same environment variable values and export them in a local terminal the result of the above command is what I expect.

My question is, when extending `SimpleBuildWrapper`, is there a step I'm missing to ensure the environment variables are exported to each subsequent shell command?

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

**UPDATE**

I have checked the output of `/usr/bin/env` and the environment variables are set. I think it may be an issue of how I am implementing the calls to `vault` it self that may be the issue. I will update this question accordingly either with an answer or more relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a step I'm missing to ensure the environment variables are exported to each subsequent shell command?

No. There is [test coverage](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/b1703f03db97d53cb73d2a08ac10a268cb7c6a2e/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/CoreWrapperStepTest.java#L81-L181) for this and it works.

You can run `/usr/bin/env` before `aws …` to see for sure what is getting set and narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just updated the question. I already examined `env` output. This may be less of a plugin API issue and more of my implementation of it. I will keep updating accordingly. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. as it turns out you are right and it works. The issue was that it takes a couple seconds for the aws iam api to make the credentials that vault supplies available. throwing a `sleep 5` in front of my aws cli command did the trick. thanks again